# Xcode Simulator Display disorder

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a problem with the Xcode Simulator display error. Every time I run simulator, the display of my UI is disordered, just like a mess, everything is messed up. however, after I scroll the view, everything went back to what it should be like. I don't know if this a Xcode bug or something I did wrong in coding?

Question 2: for UIImageView, I have set the constrains with a width: 180, height:120, and mode: aspect fill. however, when I run the simulator, the size of the image is not correct(should be rectangular, rather than square). please check the image to see my problem, thanks.

[disordered display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0t02.png)
[after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oq8W.png)

Comment: what error simulator displays ?

Comment: it seems the problem is in setting up the UI components constraints ..how you setting UI components can you explain here a bit ?

Comment: I have a TableViewCell, I set the height is 417, the ImageView is 414(width) by 231(height), and I set constrains (top:0, left:0, right:0, height:231), and below is the titleLabel, with constrains(top: 20, left:20, right:20, height: 21), below is the contentLabel, with constrains (top: 20, left:20, right:20, bottom: 20), and it will show multiple lines. @vaibhav

Comment: cant figure out your constraints prob but instead of doing so much of stuff you must use stackViews to set the UI this is more concrete way ..

Comment: I tried to rebuild the UI again, and there is no problem, I don't know why. but thanks anyway.